# C# Drawing: What is the best way to draw a polygon with a hole in the middle

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, gdi

I have a shape that is defined by an outer border and then an inner border.  IF there is no inner boarder, the shape is solid.  If there is an inner border I want the polygon/path to be defined only between the two borders; I don't want to draw the outside and then draw the inside in the background color.

For example, if I have a square defined by the following coordinates for the outside border:

```
{0,0}, {20, 0}, {20,20}, {0, 20}
```

Then that square which is 20x20 with its bottom left right corner on the origin.  That shape then has a triangle cut out of the center:

```
{10,10}, {15,10}, {15,15}
```

How can I create a path that contains this shape using either WPF or GDI+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GDI+, you can use `FillPath()` or `DrawPath()` with `FillModeAlternate`.

There's an example pretty close to what you're asking for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533922%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

You can draw that shape with XAML: (The key is to use a `CombinedGeometry` with `GeometryCombineMode="Exclude"`)

```
<Path Fill="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="10,10">
                        <LineSegment Point="15,10"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="15,15"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: +1 Worth pointing out that the key here is `GeometryCombineMode="Exclude"`

Answer (score -1):

Just draw the holes on top of the main contour using the background color. It will look as if they were real holes
***edit***
use this approach if the api you are using does not support holes. Which is why I assume you are asking

Comment: Very few APIs have no support for holes, though I've had a problem with libharu for generating PDF files in the past (still keep meaning to check if it's changed or develop a patch - PDF definitely supports compound paths). Painting a hole in the background colour only works if what you're supposed to see through the whole *is* just the background colour, of course. Even then, there can be technicalities such as the style used for edges. +1 for a simple solution for simple cases, though.

Comment: Your approach will not work if polygons should also have some transparency.

Comment: Usually if you have a hole in a polygon, you want to see the layers below or data inside the hole. If you draw the holes with the background color you will erase everything already drawn in this area.